# How can i implement "Cache-Control: no-store" and either "Pragma: no-cache" or "Cache-Control: no-cache" response directives

Tags: sharepoint-server, cache, http-headers

So our security team had an investigation in our sharepoint site and one of the things they've mention is

**DESCRIPTION**

"The application does not implement “no-store” and/or “no-cache” setting for Cache-Control and “no-cache” for Pragma headers in all of its pages. This allows SSL pages to be cached and sensitive information can be gathered which can aid an attacker on how to customize its script to exploit the application."

**RECOMMENDATION**

"Restrict the ability to cache application pages that contain sensitive data by implementing "Cache-Control: no-store" and either "Pragma: no-cache" or "Cache-Control: no-cache" response directives."

How can i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you develop a custom app you have to set headers of your calls as suggested: 
Cache-Control: no-store 
Pragma: no-cache

.js example:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        ...
    },
    body: ...
}
```

.NET example:

```
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Pragma", "no-cache");
```