# How to Set cache control directives such as 'no-store, no-cache' for all authenticated pages

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, 2019, cache

We have an internet facing web application in SharePoint and it has custom pages with some custom web parts here we require to implement the proper cache control directives for all the authenticated pages, now our security team told 'It is recommended to set proper cache control directives such as 'no-store, no-cache' for all authenticated pages.'

Now this application has implemented cache control for authenticated pages as 'Private'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer following articles to configure cache settings for a web application in the SharePoint server.

[Configure cache settings for a web application in SharePoint server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/cache-settings-configuration-for-a-web-application)

[How to modify the Cache-Control HTTP Header when you use IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/247404/how-to-modify-the-cache-control-http-header-when-you-use-iis)

[How can I implement “Cache-Control: no-store”](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/256659/how-can-i-implement-cache-control-no-store-and-either-pragma-no-cache-or)